# Java sorting ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist

Well , I'm stock on something very simple but I can't figure it out.

First off, I know that there is `Collection.sort()` method, but my ArrayList is sort of links to data to main object, and my sorting is needed to be made according to this object's data.

Like this is a sport competition and `ArrayList<Integer> numbers` is keeping numbers of participants that has passed a checkpoint.

And I need to sort this ArrayList by the best time from min to max to set them on who's on 1st place, 2nd etc.

for this I should ask my Competiton object :

```
    public ArrayList<Integer> sort (ArrayList<Integer> numbers)
    for (int i=0;i<numbers.size){
    long time = competition.participant.get(numbers.get(i)).getTimeOfLastCheckPoint();
    /*Do something to make another ArrayList<Integer> sortedArray
 where all this will be sorted by this time parameter from minimal to maximum*/
    return sortedArray;
    }
```

this is not the actual code, but you've got the idea. I stuck with trying to find seemingly easy solution. 
Please Help

Answer (score 3):

It seems awkward to sort an `ArrayList<Integer>` based on other things that have nothing directly to do with what you actually want to sort on -- the times.

I would design it differently.  It looks you have some kind of object defined on which you can call `getTimeOfLastCheckPoint()`.  For now, I'm assuming it's called `Participant`.  Instead of maintaining an `ArrayList<Integer>` to store index-based references to your participants, I would maintain an `ArrayList<Participant>`.

Then I would create a class that implements `Comparator<Participant>` (perhaps `ParticipantComparator`) ([`Comparator` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) that knows how to compare `Participant`s based on the results of the call to `getTimeOfLastCheckPoint()`.  Then sorting is simply `Collections.sort(participantsArrayList, new ParticipantComparator());`.

Comment: this ArrayList<Integer> I give to my custom ListAdapter which extracts a lot of data from this numbers. Like i pass ArrayList<Integer> numbers to adapter and it set on List participant's name under this number, his name , team, etc. the root object I have there is Competition, it has a List for example of 150 objects of Participants where data about time, and so on is stiored. So I don't pass alot of data to adapter, only link to them in my ArrayList<Integer>

Answer (score 3):

Write a `java.util.Comparator` that compares `Integer`s by using them as index in your participants-array:

```
public class ParticipantIndexComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
    final List<Participant> participants;
    public ParticipantIndexComparator(List<Participant> participants) {
        this.participants = participants;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        long l1 = participants.get(i1).getTimeOfLastCheckPoint();
        long l2 = participants.get(i2).getTimeOfLastCheckPoint();
        return Long.compare(l1, l2);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this comparator to sort your integers:

```
Collections.sort(numbers, new ParticipantIndexComparator(participants));
```

But before doing so, ask yourself why your list contains `Integer`-objects that are indices to the participants-list, instead of the `Participant`s themselves!

Answer (score 2):

For me, this sounds like a workaround solution for a half-done SQL query. In case that your data resides in a data base (and I'm pretty sure that this is the case), modify your SQL- query so that you don't have to do that sorting of data at application level. This is good for at least two reasons:

1. Simplyfiy application logic
2. Speed up execution (The data base can do such sorting much faster)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to sort the list according to their race duration and also use for-each loop in Java.